# Ajax seems to execute only once

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm using Jquery's ajax method to update the data on the screen (go to the next data item in the database). When I click the next button I want it to go to the data record with the next id `(current_id + 1)`. It works on the first click but not after that (The text no longer updates/changes), I'm pretty new to Django and WebDev so let me know if you need any more context.

Here's the jquery code:

```
{% block javascript %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','#next',function(){
        var id = "{{record.id}}";
        console.log(id)
        $.ajax({
            url : "{% url 'next' %}",
            data : {'id':id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(data){
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
                $("#word").text(data['word']);
                $("#meaning").text(data['meaning']);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's the code for the view that handles the request:

```
def next(response):
    id = int(response.GET.get('id',None))
    record = Words.objects.filter(id = id+1).first()
    data = {
        'word' : record.word,
        'meaning' : record.meaning
    }

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: So what happens on second click? You haven't provided any debugging details. Without any context the term "doesn't work" is virtually meaningless

Comment: You are incrementing id in your view, but you're not updating the id for the subsequent json requests. Return the new id in your json data and update the var id.

Comment: @RobVezina Thanks, I had a feeling it had something to do with the id not updating,

Comment: @charliefl, by "doesn't work" I meant that the html text doesn't update. I'll edit the question anyway.